# Alternative solution for 100 prisoners problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, puzzle

I recently heard about the 100 prisoners problem ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/100_prisoners_problem ) and have two questions about it.

1. Let's assume a cycle with length $l$ > 50, then there are $\binom{100}{l}$ possibilities to choose numbers for such a cycle. After choosing $l$ numbers I would assume that there are $l\ !$ possibilities to arrange them in a cycle. We still have $(100-l)$ remaining numbers, which we can arrange by $(100-l)!$ possibilities. All together I get 
   \begin{align}
   \binom{100}{l}\cdot l\ !\cdot(100-l)!
   \end{align}
   possibilities for getting a cycle with $l\ >\ 0$. But I found out that the correct formula is
   \begin{align}
   \binom{100}{l}\cdot \color{red}{(l-1)\ !}\cdot(100-l)!
   \end{align}
   $\mathbf{Why}$ $\color{red}{(l-1)\ !}$ $\mathbf{?}$
2. It has been shown that the optimal policy "wins" in about 30 %, independently of the number of prisoners. Furthermore it has been shown that this is an optimum, thus there is no better policy. But if we get cycles with $l>50$, this policy $\mathbf{always}$ fails. I wonder if there could be another policy which works as good as the already known policy, but whose success is $\mathbf{independent}$ of the length of the cycles.

Comment: For question 2, I am not aware of a proof that this strategy is optimal.  It seems like it should be as the probability of success is rather high.  It is often difficult to prove opimality because you have to imagine all the other possible strategies.  Sometimes you can because there is some constraint and you can say "if you don't do it this way, it will be worse".

Comment: I have a lot of math, but I never studied combinatorics, so there's one term I don't understand. Nor do I know how to typeset it here. so it's the two big parentheses with 100 on top of the letter el. What does that mean?

Comment: @MiguelMunoz: It is the binomial coefficient, see explanation here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Answer (score 1):

**1.**  You can always choose some person to "start" the cycle, and the remaining can be arranged in $(l-1)!$ ways. For example, there are only 1 way to organize 2 persons into a cycle.

**2.** There's a nice way to overcome this by randomizing the algorithm. Namely, the prisoners should choose a random permutation $\sigma$ beforehand and apply it. Namely, the prisoner $k$ should start from $\sigma(k)$ and then at each step she should open the box $\sigma(x)$, where $x$ is her number. 
This randomized strategy has the same probability of succeeding, no matter what the initial position is.

Answer (score 0):

**Ad 1.**

$l$ numbers can be permutated in $l!$ ways, but some of these permutations represents the same cycle, eg. permutations $4,5,6,1,2,3$ and $2,3,4,5,6,1$ represents the same cycle $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$. There are exactly $l$ permutations in this equivalence class, so the number of cycles is equal to $\frac{l!}{l}=(l-1)!$

**Ad 2.**

This $31\%$ is probability where **every prisoner draws his number**, ie. in our permutation there is no cycle with length $l>50$. No matter of the length of cycles, if prosoners choose this strategy they have $31\%$ chance to win.

To show what I mean, assume that you have to guess the number drawn on 6 sided dice. Let's say, that your strategy is to say, that the drawn number is $5$. It gives you $16,6\%$ chances to win and $83,4\%$ chances to loose. Saying that your strategy fails when the drawn number is different than $5$ is the same as saying, that your strategy works perfectly when the drawn number is $5$.

As far as you don't know what the number is, you have $16,6\%$ chances to win.

As far, as the prosoners don't know if there is a cycle with length $l>50$, they have $31\%$ chance to win.